# Modeling Datastore (Google App Engine) entities with UML (class diagram)

Tags: google-app-engine, uml, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling, class-diagram

I'm trying to make a data modeling of my entities in Datastore GAE. Can anyone help me how to make it using UML (class diagram) ? 
Which type of UML class relations corresponds with parent-child entities? And how to modeling one-to-one / one-to-many relations? and unidirectionnal/bidirectionnal relations with UML?

Answer (score 1):

for One-to-Many (not-cascade):aggregation
[image]
for one-to-many (cascade):composition
[image]
for one-to-one: association
[image]

but I have to say, these diagram may don't fit with your system, because the business would affect the diagrams, I would call them generic.